# Code formating on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

When I edit this answer, *[Installing PERCL GeoIP for PHP on windows XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575415/installing-percl-geoip-for-php-on-windows-xampp#answer-46784247)*,

`<IfModule geoip_module>
        GeoIPEnable On
        GeoIPDBFile bin/GeoIP.dat
    </IfModule>`

I removed ` from code and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to format.

[image: Issue]

See, the code is not formatting.

Please guide me how to formatting this issue.

Comment: Code within itemizations/enumerations need to be indented by further 4 spaces per indentation level.